# How to transform the items of a list into a unique number without square brackets in NetLogo?

Tags: netlogo

I have the following doubt:

I have 31 turtle profiles as a result of combining 5 habitat types. That is:

```
profile1: turtles are only born in habitat 1
profile2: turtles are only born in habitat 2
profile3: turtles are only born in habitat 3
profile4: turtles are only born in habitat 4
profile5: turtles are only born in habitat 5
profile6: turtles are only born in habitats 1 and 2
profile7: turtles are only born in habitats 1 and 3
... until you reach profile 31: where the turtles are born in habitats 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5
```

I would like to have the information of the list and transform the item of each list removing the brackets and the spaces to have a code.

```
For example:

I am turtle: 0 the possible habitats: [1] my code: 1M1R1 my code reproduction level: R1 my code metabolism level: M1

I am turtle: 9 the possible habitats: [2] my code: 2M1R1 my code reproduction level: R1 my code metabolism level: M1

I am turtle: 45 the possible habitats: [1 2] my code: 12M1R1 my code reproduction level: R1 my code metabolism level: M1

I am turtle: 135 the possible habitats: [1 2 3] my code: 123M1R1 my code reproduction level: R1 my code metabolism level: M1
```

But what I have is:

```
I am turtle: 0 the possible habitats: [1] my code: [1]M1R1 my code reproduction level: R1 my code metabolism level: M1

I am turtle: 9 the possible habitats: [2] my code: [2]M1R1 my code reproduction level: R1 my code metabolism level: M1
    
I am turtle: 45 the possible habitats: [1 2] my code: [1 2]M1R1 my code reproduction level: R1 my code metabolism level: M1
    
I am turtle: 135 the possible habitats: [1 2 3] my code: [1 2 3]M1R1 my code reproduction level: R1 my code metabolism level: M1
```

Is it possible to do what I want?

Thanks in advance

Please see the command center of the code below:

```
globals [ ValidHabs ]

to setup
  clear-all
  read     
end

to read
  set ValidHabs [ ]
   
  ; the ValidHabs in the original code is a list created from a .csv file. Here I created a list in the code to exemplify...
  set ValidHabs [ [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [1 2] [1 3] [1 4] [1 5] [2 3] [2 4] [2 5] [3 4] [3 5] [4 5] [1 2 3] [1 2 4] [1 2 5] [1 3 4] [1 3 5] [1 4 5] [2 3 4] [2 3 5] [2 4 5] [3 4 5] [1 2 3 4] [1 2 3 5] [1 2 4 5] [1 3 4 5] [2 3 4 5] [1 2 3 4 5] ]
  show ValidHabs
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just make a string of the hole list by using `reduce` and `word`

As example:

```
to go
  show reduce_list [1 2 3 4 5] ; shows "12345"
end

to-report reduce_list [a_list]
  report reduce word a_list
end
```

Comment: Hi Lena, Thanks!!! It helped a lot... :)

Comment: Hi Lena, I made your suggestion and the following error appeared: ITEM expected input to be a number but got the string "12" instead. Is there any way to adjust this? Thanks

turtles-own [ turtle-profiles-habitat-code turtle-profiles-habitat ]

to go  
  set turtle-profiles-habitat[ [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [1 2] [1 3] [1 4] [1 5] [2 3] ] 
  ask turtle who [
    set turtle-profiles-habitat-code reduce_list turtle-profiles-habitat
    print ( word "habitatcover profile code: " turtle-profiles-habitat-code )
  ]
end

to-report reduce_list [ a_list ]
  report reduce word a_list
end

Comment: I don't understand, where the error is comming from. It's certainly not in the code, that you gave in the comment, because there is no `item`.

Comment: Hi Lena, thanks for the reply. It's just that I didn't have space to put all the code here (comment). But, I opened a question at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70809554/how-to-resolve-the-error-item-expected-input-to-be-a-number-but-got-the- string and the code is all there from the error. If you can help me one more time I appreciate it :)

Comment: Solved the problem. This suggestion helped a lot. Thanks :)